# C char array v C char* initialization

Tags: c, string, initialization, declaration

The following is accepted as valid `c` code by `gcc` version 6.3:

```
char white[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
char blue[]  = "abc";
char *red    = "abc";
```

However the following fails:

```
 char *green = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };   // gcc error
```

I am sure there is a perfectly rational reason for this to be the case, but I am wondering what it is. This question is motivated by the case when having to initialize an array of bytes (so `unsigned char` rather than `char`), it is very tempting to write something like `{ '\x43', '\xde', '\xa0' }` rather than `"\x43\xde\xa0"`, and as soon as you forget to write `my_array[]` instead of `*my_array`, you get caught by the compiler.

Comment: Your definition of `white` is not equivalent to the other two, because it is missing the null-terminator (`\0`) at the end of the string.

Comment: @abelenky oh yes, this is a good point which I overlooked, thank you.

Comment: try `char *green = { "a", "b", "c" };`.... ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following will produce an error

```
char *green = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
```

Because the initializer for `green` isn't an array of characters as you believe. It doesn't have a type, it's just a brace-enclosed initializer list. The thing that it initializes in the previous samples (i.e. `white`) determines how it's interpreted. The same initialzier can be used to initialize any aggregate that is capable of holding 3 characters.

But `green` is a pointer, and not an aggregate, so you can't use a brace-enclosed initializer list as it's initial value.<sup>1</sup>

Now, the following two work but with very different semantics:

```
char blue[]  = "abc";
char *red    = "abc";
```

`blue` is an array. It will hold the same contents as the literal `"abc"`. `red` is a pointer that *points* at the literal `"abc"`.

---

1. You can use a [compound literal expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal):

   ```
   char *green = (char[]){ 'a', 'b', 'c' };
   ```

   It tells the compiler to create an unnamed object (the life time of which depends on the scope of the declaration), that is of character array type and is initialized with those three characters. The pointer is then assigned the address of that object.

Comment: All very true.  The answer would be even better, however, if it showed how the `char *` declaration could be corrected by changing the initializer list into a `char`-array literal (as opposed to a string literal), and by discussing the significance of doing so.

Comment: @JohnBollinger - I was just typing in the info about compound literals

Comment: @StoryTeller Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 6):

These three declarations

```
char white[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
char blue[]  = "abc";
char *red    = "abc";
```

are different.

The first one declares a character array that contains exactly three characters corresponding to the number of the initializers.

The second one declares a character array of four characters because it is initialized by a string literal that has four characters including the terminating zero. So this character array contains a string.

The third one defined a string literal that is a character array and declares a pointer of type `char *` that is initialized by the address of the first character of the character array corresponding to the string literal.

You can imagine this declaration like

```
char unnamed = { 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0' };
char *red = unnamed;
```

This declaration

```
char *green = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
```

is invalid because the left object is a scalar and may not be initialized by a list that contains more than one initializer.

Take into account that you could use a compound literal to initialize the pointer. For example

```
char *green = ( char[] ){ 'a', 'b', 'c' };
```

Comment: Thank you very much